# I can't get the example connect properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I started working with the Alexa skills kit earlier this week. The development of the skill itself wasnt terrible, as I got my skill to work just fine when connected to the ARN and running through the simulator. However, I wanted to test it on my actual Alexa device, so I deployed it to lamba, as the tutorial specified. I'm fairly inexperienced with network/server management, so perhaps I've set up something wrong with the nginx proxy. When I attempt to access the url in the management console via a webpage, I get a 502(rightfully so, as the app should be looking on 443, if I understand correctly). This is then reflected in the nginxaccess and nginxerror logs, so I know I am actually connecting to the proxy server. When I look at the node logs, it reads

Virtual_Dungeon_Master@0.0.5 start /var/app/current
node index.js
looped and repeated a whole bunch. This is with a freshly unzipped sample helloWorld src file. I think there is a decent chance the issue lies with my app ID. I put my app id in like this.

var APP_ID = 'amzn1.ask.skill.[zzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzz]';`

It matches with the one in my skill configuration, so I doubt that is it. When I try and connect to it via the skill simulator, it reads "The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid." I checked the console, and it says the response was the following.

angular.js:12808TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of null
at d.invokeSkillWithTextAsync.then.a.textRequest

Also of note, when I try and connect via the skill simulator, it does not record the events in the logs. This leads me to believe there is some sort of issue in the connection between the outside and the proxy server via https. If I change the deployment to the amazon sample http deployment running a node server, it works fine, and I get the served the stock sample index page in my web browser just fine. Is there anything else I can check?

Also, I apologize if I'm being needlessly wordy, but I want to make this post easier for search engines to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.  The problem is that it was deployed on Lambda, and I was running the code on an EC2 instance.  I just had to use the ARN to test it on my device